# How to securely store and manage Google Cloud Storage key (json file)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am writing an application where I have to upload media files to GCS. So, I created a storage bucket and also created a service account which is being used by the application to put and get images from the bucket. To access this service account from the application I had to generate a private key as a ***JSON*** file.

I am tested my code and it is working fine. Now, I want to push this code to my Github repository but I don't want this service account key to be in Github.

How do I manage to keep this service account key secret, yet all my fellow colleagues should be able to use it.

I am going to put my application on GCP Container Instance and I want it to work there as well.

Comment: If you will put your application in a container running on GCP (with a VM), there is no need to have a JSON key file of your service account. Just use the service account as the VM service account. If you want to test it locally, you will need a JSON key file; you can put it in Secret Manager.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you use the credentials? I will update it and explain you how to avoid to use service account key files!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, if your application works from inside the GCP and use some custom service account, you might not need any private keys (as json files) at all.

The custom service account, which is used by your application, should get relevant IAM roles/permissions on the correspondent GCS bucket. And that's all you might need to do.

You can assign those IAM roles/permissions either manually (through UI console), or using CLI commands, or as part of your deployment CI/CD pipeline.